# How to set priority of searched result by pg_search gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pg-search

I have used the `pg_search` gem and it works awesome but now I want to get the first result of the search by `product_name`, then get the result of `description`.

This is the code I am using:

```
pg_search_scope :whose_name_starts_with,
   :against => [:product_name,:description],
   :using => {
     :tsearch => {:dictionary => "english",:prefix => true,:any_word => true},
     :trigram  => {},
     :dmetaphone => {:any_word => true, :sort_only => true}
   }
```

I have used Weighting but it gives me the same results as before. How can I fix this code?